# Problem when exporting .svg to TikZ code on MacOS

Tags: tikz-pgf, svg

I'm trying to convert a `svg` file into tikz code using Inkscape and the `svg2tikz` extension downloaded from https://github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz. I've done this before under Windows 10, but this time I'm using MacOS. There's no `.tex` file generated and I get this output:

```
tikz_export.py:645: DeprecationWarning: Effect.OptionParser or `optparse` has been deprecated and replaced with `argparser`.You must change `self.OptionParser.add_option` to `self.arg_parser.add_argument`; the arguments are similar.
  parser = self.OptionParser
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tikz_export.py", line 1478, in <module>
    main_inkscape()
  File "tikz_export.py", line 1461, in main_inkscape
    effect = TikZPathExporter(inkscape_mode=True)
  File "tikz_export.py", line 629, in __init__
    self._set_up_options()
  File "tikz_export.py", line 646, in _set_up_options
    parser.set_defaults(codeoutput='standalone', crop=False, clipboard=False,
AttributeError: 'TikZPathExporter' object has no attribute 'set_defaults'
```

Here is the content of this `svg` file:

```
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1200px" height="1200px" viewBox="0 0 12000 12000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"><g fill="#14120b"><path d="M0 6000 l0-6000 6000 0 6000 0 0 6000 0 6000-6000 0-6000 0 0-6000z"/></g><g fill="#ffffff"><path d="M0 6000 l0-6000 6000 0 6000 0 0 6000 0 6000-6000 0-6000 0 0-6000z m11506 4617 c82-46 89-81 27-138-47-45-105-68-316-125-457-124-692-201-1047-341-146-58-305-121-355-140-272-108-644-321-1298-743-272-176-885-635-1207-904-206-173-564-532-802-806-271-312-348-405-348-419 0-6 56-100 123-209 354-565 729-1243 892-1612 153-345 302-791 370-1102 51-237 20-367-73-302-31 22-47 55-108 236-81 238-120 316-306 615-48 79-152 254-229 390-252 441-447 758-720 1169-147 221-271 404-277 408-5 3-93-88-194-202-191-214-643-684-866-900-208-202-293-265-512-382-74-40-153-85-175-100-22-15-50-30-63-34-12-4-20-12-17-17 4-5-8-9-24-9-37 0-42 27-10 56 11 10 27 32 34 49 21 50 105 161 236 315 142 165 210 252 402 505 74 99 222 286 328 415 182 223 518 654 548 704 14 22 9 30-99 172-469 616-943 1137-1367 1501-421 362-756 600-1028 733-152 75-210 93-410 130-191 35-215 43-215 69 0 11-3 26-6 34-7 18 81 108 145 149 25 16 77 38 115 50 195 59 538-38 937-265 559-317 1140-786 1588-1283 176-194 416-488 561-686 63-86 118-157 122-157 3-1 71 79 149 177 386 480 562 675 854 948 306 286 437 396 802 670 468 353 962 648 1345 803 267 108 661 240 948 317 113 31 300 82 415 114 335 94 556 145 750 173 17 3 98 4 180 3 145-1 152-2 201-29z m-9786-6023 c394-45 809-137 2000-444 852-219 1684-397 2615-560 1605-281 1819-312 2680-399 1181-119 1420-134 1914-121 305 8 357 7 382-5 75-40 85-177 17-259-41-50-130-93-265-127-274-69-435-67-1453 17-538 44-713 63-1140 124-466 67-1789 303-2385 425-148 31-349 72-445 91-583 116-2033 471-2713 665-773 219-1385 320-1761 290-156-13-308-41-391-72-74-27-167-91-196-134-23-33-40-38-68-21-20 13-6 79 32 150 104 195 352 341 652 385 100 14 381 12 525-5z m4608-2340 c101-42 152-148 122-253-16-56-57-106-169-207-230-207-526-363-831-438-136-33-502-96-560-96-91 0-121 59-52 104 20 14 101 55 180 91 297 137 478 265 734 517 216 214 350 296 486 297 29 1 69-6 90-15z"/></g></svg>
```

Comment: This extension seem to use python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way, Ti*k*Z support directly svg path through the `svg.path` library therefore with some copy and paste you can get:

[image]

The code is:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\definecolor{PathColor}{HTML}{14120b}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[fill=PathColor]
\pgfpathsvg{M0 6000 l0-6000 6000 0 6000 0 0 6000 0 6000-6000 0-6000 0 0-6000z m11506 4617 c82-46 89-81 27-138-47-45-105-68-316-125-457-124-692-201-1047-341-146-58-305-121-355-140-272-108-644-321-1298-743-272-176-885-635-1207-904-206-173-564-532-802-806-271-312-348-405-348-419 0-6 56-100 123-209 354-565 729-1243 892-1612 153-345 302-791 370-1102 51-237 20-367-73-302-31 22-47 55-108 236-81 238-120 316-306 615-48 79-152 254-229 390-252 441-447 758-720 1169-147 221-271 404-277 408-5 3-93-88-194-202-191-214-643-684-866-900-208-202-293-265-512-382-74-40-153-85-175-100-22-15-50-30-63-34-12-4-20-12-17-17 4-5-8-9-24-9-37 0-42 27-10 56 11 10 27 32 34 49 21 50 105 161 236 315 142 165 210 252 402 505 74 99 222 286 328 415 182 223 518 654 548 704 14 22 9 30-99 172-469 616-943 1137-1367 1501-421 362-756 600-1028 733-152 75-210 93-410 130-191 35-215 43-215 69 0 11-3 26-6 34-7 18 81 108 145 149 25 16 77 38 115 50 195 59 538-38 937-265 559-317 1140-786 1588-1283 176-194 416-488 561-686 63-86 118-157 122-157 3-1 71 79 149 177 386 480 562 675 854 948 306 286 437 396 802 670 468 353 962 648 1345 803 267 108 661 240 948 317 113 31 300 82 415 114 335 94 556 145 750 173 17 3 98 4 180 3 145-1 152-2 201-29z m-9786-6023 c394-45 809-137 2000-444 852-219 1684-397 2615-560 1605-281 1819-312 2680-399 1181-119 1420-134 1914-121 305 8 357 7 382-5 75-40 85-177 17-259-41-50-130-93-265-127-274-69-435-67-1453 17-538 44-713 63-1140 124-466 67-1789 303-2385 425-148 31-349 72-445 91-583 116-2033 471-2713 665-773 219-1385 320-1761 290-156-13-308-41-391-72-74-27-167-91-196-134-23-33-40-38-68-21-20 13-6 79 32 150 104 195 352 341 652 385 100 14 381 12 525-5z m4608-2340 c101-42 152-148 122-253-16-56-57-106-169-207-230-207-526-363-831-438-136-33-502-96-560-96-91 0-121 59-52 104 20 14 101 55 180 91 297 137 478 265 734 517 216 214 350 296 486 297 29 1 69-6 90-15z}
\pgfusepath{fill}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT upside down**

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
    \definecolor{PathColor}{HTML}{14120b}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[fill=PathColor,yscale=-1]
    \pgfpathsvg{M0 6000 l0-6000 6000 0 6000 0 0 6000 0 6000-6000 0-6000 0 0-6000z m11506 4617 c82-46 89-81 27-138-47-45-105-68-316-125-457-124-692-201-1047-341-146-58-305-121-355-140-272-108-644-321-1298-743-272-176-885-635-1207-904-206-173-564-532-802-806-271-312-348-405-348-419 0-6 56-100 123-209 354-565 729-1243 892-1612 153-345 302-791 370-1102 51-237 20-367-73-302-31 22-47 55-108 236-81 238-120 316-306 615-48 79-152 254-229 390-252 441-447 758-720 1169-147 221-271 404-277 408-5 3-93-88-194-202-191-214-643-684-866-900-208-202-293-265-512-382-74-40-153-85-175-100-22-15-50-30-63-34-12-4-20-12-17-17 4-5-8-9-24-9-37 0-42 27-10 56 11 10 27 32 34 49 21 50 105 161 236 315 142 165 210 252 402 505 74 99 222 286 328 415 182 223 518 654 548 704 14 22 9 30-99 172-469 616-943 1137-1367 1501-421 362-756 600-1028 733-152 75-210 93-410 130-191 35-215 43-215 69 0 11-3 26-6 34-7 18 81 108 145 149 25 16 77 38 115 50 195 59 538-38 937-265 559-317 1140-786 1588-1283 176-194 416-488 561-686 63-86 118-157 122-157 3-1 71 79 149 177 386 480 562 675 854 948 306 286 437 396 802 670 468 353 962 648 1345 803 267 108 661 240 948 317 113 31 300 82 415 114 335 94 556 145 750 173 17 3 98 4 180 3 145-1 152-2 201-29z m-9786-6023 c394-45 809-137 2000-444 852-219 1684-397 2615-560 1605-281 1819-312 2680-399 1181-119 1420-134 1914-121 305 8 357 7 382-5 75-40 85-177 17-259-41-50-130-93-265-127-274-69-435-67-1453 17-538 44-713 63-1140 124-466 67-1789 303-2385 425-148 31-349 72-445 91-583 116-2033 471-2713 665-773 219-1385 320-1761 290-156-13-308-41-391-72-74-27-167-91-196-134-23-33-40-38-68-21-20 13-6 79 32 150 104 195 352 341 652 385 100 14 381 12 525-5z m4608-2340 c101-42 152-148 122-253-16-56-57-106-169-207-230-207-526-363-831-438-136-33-502-96-560-96-91 0-121 59-52 104 20 14 101 55 180 91 297 137 478 265 734 517 216 214 350 296 486 297 29 1 69-6 90-15z}
    \pgfusepath{fill}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT Background color**

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\definecolor{PathColor}{HTML}{14120b}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[fill=PathColor,yscale=-1]
\pgfpathsvg{M0 6000 l0-6000 6000 0 6000 0 0 6000 0 6000-6000 0-6000 0 0-6000z}
\pgfusepath{discard}
\pgfpathsvg{M0 6000 m11506 4617 c82-46 89-81 27-138-47-45-105-68-316-125-457-124-692-201-1047-341-146-58-305-121-355-140-272-108-644-321-1298-743-272-176-885-635-1207-904-206-173-564-532-802-806-271-312-348-405-348-419 0-6 56-100 123-209 354-565 729-1243 892-1612 153-345 302-791 370-1102 51-237 20-367-73-302-31 22-47 55-108 236-81 238-120 316-306 615-48 79-152 254-229 390-252 441-447 758-720 1169-147 221-271 404-277 408-5 3-93-88-194-202-191-214-643-684-866-900-208-202-293-265-512-382-74-40-153-85-175-100-22-15-50-30-63-34-12-4-20-12-17-17 4-5-8-9-24-9-37 0-42 27-10 56 11 10 27 32 34 49 21 50 105 161 236 315 142 165 210 252 402 505 74 99 222 286 328 415 182 223 518 654 548 704 14 22 9 30-99 172-469 616-943 1137-1367 1501-421 362-756 600-1028 733-152 75-210 93-410 130-191 35-215 43-215 69 0 11-3 26-6 34-7 18 81 108 145 149 25 16 77 38 115 50 195 59 538-38 937-265 559-317 1140-786 1588-1283 176-194 416-488 561-686 63-86 118-157 122-157 3-1 71 79 149 177 386 480 562 675 854 948 306 286 437 396 802 670 468 353 962 648 1345 803 267 108 661 240 948 317 113 31 300 82 415 114 335 94 556 145 750 173 17 3 98 4 180 3 145-1 152-2 201-29z m-9786-6023 c394-45 809-137 2000-444 852-219 1684-397 2615-560 1605-281 1819-312 2680-399 1181-119 1420-134 1914-121 305 8 357 7 382-5 75-40 85-177 17-259-41-50-130-93-265-127-274-69-435-67-1453 17-538 44-713 63-1140 124-466 67-1789 303-2385 425-148 31-349 72-445 91-583 116-2033 471-2713 665-773 219-1385 320-1761 290-156-13-308-41-391-72-74-27-167-91-196-134-23-33-40-38-68-21-20 13-6 79 32 150 104 195 352 341 652 385 100 14 381 12 525-5z m4608-2340 c101-42 152-148 122-253-16-56-57-106-169-207-230-207-526-363-831-438-136-33-502-96-560-96-91 0-121 59-52 104 20 14 101 55 180 91 297 137 478 265 734 517 216 214 350 296 486 297 29 1 69-6 90-15z}
\pgfusepath{fill}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! However there's a little problem: the picture is upside down. How should I fix this?

Comment: you must use `yscale=-1`

Comment: I forgot to mention that the background color and picture color is wrong too, the background should be transparent and the picture should be black. How can I change the color of it?

Comment: I think that it is the opposite area that should be selected and filled, is there an option like `inverse path` for this propose?

Comment: For the background problem I don't have found any solutions without modifying a little the path. You must put a part or delete the first part of the path between `l ... z`.