# Can't export SVG image to Tikz file from Inkscape 1.0.1 on Windows using Inkscape2Tikz extension

Tags: tikz-pgf, svg, inkscape

I am trying to export an image from Inkscape to a .tex file with the extension Inkscape2Tikz downloaded from GitHub, but it won't work.
I managed to include the extension in Inkscape and when I try to use it will give the following error and won't save the .tex file:

```
tikz_export.py:645: DeprecationWarning: Effect.OptionParser or `optparse` has been deprecated and replaced with `argparser`.You must change `self.OptionParser.add_option` to `self.arg_parser.add_argument`; the arguments are similar.
  parser = self.OptionParser
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tikz_export.py", line 1478, in <module>
    main_inkscape()
  File "tikz_export.py", line 1461, in main_inkscape
    effect = TikZPathExporter(inkscape_mode=True)
  File "tikz_export.py", line 629, in __init__
    self._set_up_options()
  File "tikz_export.py", line 646, in _set_up_options
    parser.set_defaults(codeoutput='standalone', crop=False, clipboard=False,
AttributeError: 'TikZPathExporter' object has no attribute 'set_defaults'
```

I have already seen people suggesting to use the PDF+LaTex option in Inkscape, but I will need the entire Tikz tex file due to the fact that the final file must not exceed a very low limit of size.
I have found other people complaining about this issue but still no answer nor effective solution.
Thank you very much for your help!! It will be very appreciated.

Comment: If I am not mistaking, that extension is not compatible with the version of inkscape.

Comment: [Similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/570912/162128) few days ago.

Comment: Are you sure that the compiled document will be (considerably) larger if you use the `svg` package (effectively Inkscape's PDF+LaTeX export) instead of exporting to Ti*k*Z code?

Comment: @azetina I guess you're right, I tried to use it with the Inkscape 0.48 version and it worked altough it gave me an output file which was cosinderably larger than I thought, and thus useless.

Comment: @schtandard Since I have a seriously limited dimension allowed (500kb for an entire document) I am looking for a way to get even a little reduction in size. Unfortunately, the PDF+LaTex format doesn't give me that reduction compared to the SVG or EPS original image.